# Changing the default TeXlipse compiler to PDFLatex

Tags: errors, pdf, texlipse, eclipse

I just installed TeXlipse, and want to make my `.tex`-file alongside my Java-code (in the same Java-project). Right now, I can compile, but only to `.dvi`, which I dislike because of the bad viewer.

Is it possible to change the default extension to `.pdf`, for every project?
I already tried to disable the `.dvi` and `.ps` compilers by removing their program file path, but then I'm getting the error:

```
Error: Builder (#0) for dvi output format has an invalid configuration: <project-name>.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you probably have a Java project with a `.tex` file somewhere. Something like the following image:

[image: Image 1]

If we save our document, TeXlipse is configured to run the TeX builder for us. Saving the document with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> will give us the following files in my `doc/` subfolder:

[image: Image 2]

The default setup is to rely on `latex` and `.dvi`. In order to change this behaviour, we need to go to `Project > Properties`:

[image: Image 3]

Just a note: if we check the builders, we will see that the project is set to run both Java and TeX builders for us.

[image: Image 4]

Look for the `LaTeX Project Properties` tab:

[image: Image 5]

The following screen will appear:

[image: Image 6]

Go to the output format and change the extension from `.dvi` to `.pdf`:

[image: Image 7]

The engine will automatically change to `pdflatex`. Click `OK`.

[image: Image 8]

Every time we edit our `.tex` document and save it, `pdflatex` will be executed instead of `latex`, and we will have the following files in my `doc/` subfolder:

[image: Image 9]

We can also see the `.pdf` with the embedded viewer:

[image: Image 10]

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: Great answer, Paulo! Unfortunately I can’t upvote, because I cannot verify it (no Eclipse user).

Comment: What?! No, “<3”? I am very, veerry, VERY sad!!!11 ;-)

Comment: @Speravir: oops, my bad. `<3` `:)`

Comment: Wow, great answer! Big thanks, indeed works!

Comment: And now, when Pieter as the OP said, it was helpful, I will upvote in a second.

Comment: @Speravir: `<3<3<3` `:)`

Comment: [Not today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635523/builder-2-for-pdf-output-format-has-an-invalid-configuration), not for me. :/

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Implicitly, the OP wants a central option somewhere so that all future LaTeX projects will compile with pdflatex, whereas this answer requires each project to be configured upon creation which from my own experience is quite irritating. I actually came here looking for a central option and have yet to find one.

Comment: @JoelWallman: this is what TeXlipse had to offer by that time. If you find a better way, please add an answer. This is the best I could find.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you never use .dvi, then you can set the default behavior for all new projects to mimic that of the .pdf behavior by overwriting the latex.exe settings with the pdflatex settings. To do this, go to

```
Window>Preference>Texlipse>Builder Settings
```

Click on "Pdflatex program", then click edit and copy the contents of the "arguments" box. Close and open the options for "Latex program". Paste the arguments from the "Pdflatex program" options into the corresponding box and change the "program file" from DIR/latex.exe to DIR/pdflatex.exe

Note that Eclipse will now expect the output to be .dvi and so won't:
a) launch the correct previewer using ctrl-4
b) remove the compiled pdf if you run the clean command.

I am "fine" with this hack and its consequences as I use pdf4eclipse with ctrl-alt-F for forward search, but would like there to be a central option.